# How can I translate dynamic sentence with react i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

So I want something like this to show on my page:

**`there are ${number} monkeys living in our zoo`**

so the number is a number got from server

My question is how to use `t` function from react-18nex to do it and what should I do in my locales files for translate?

many thanks

Comment: You should separate it to three sections: first static part+ dynamic part + second static part. And use `t` function for two static parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{ }} in your language json file like,

```
hello: "hello, {{username}}"
```

and use it like that:

```
 i18n.t("hello",{username:"hasankzl"})
```